# Image disappears when adding event directly on image

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am adding an event this image and it just disappears when adding said even i wonder if i use an icon and css it would show up

here is the component

```cs
    @inherits SelectUserListComponentBase
    
    <h3>Selected User List</h3>
    
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @if(!SelectedUsers.Any())
        {
            <div>No Users</div>
        }
        else
        {
             <div>
                <ul class="ppt">
                @foreach(var u in SelectedUsers.Keys)
                {
                    <li>@u</li>
                    <image id="@u" @onclick="async ()=>{ await this.DeleteuserEvent.InvokeAsync(u);}" src="/images/icons/icons-remove.png"></image>
                }
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

even adding as an icon and directly linking to said image it not showing up

````
cs
<i style="background-image:url('/images/icons/icons-remove.png')" @onclick="async ()=>{ await this.DeleteuserEvent.InvokeAsync(u);}" ></i>```
````

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<img />` instead of `<image></image>`?

Comment: @Dimitris Maragkos well eah I ended also finding the same issue with using a span and a background image but I found i could use font awesome instead